# Missing old HDD Firefox profile after installing windows 10 on SSD

Tags: windows-10, firefox, user-profiles

I had a PC with Windows 8 installed that had Firefox.

I decided to upgrade it to SSD, and to install Windows 10 fresh (not as upgrade) to the SSD.

The install went smoothly, with one (possibly important) detail - I used the same user name for my main user on Windows 10 and old Windows 8 (whose drive is now "D:" - I installed SSD as disk 0 before the install, and moved old HDD as disk #1)

When I installed FireFox on Windows 10, I went ahead to copy the old FF profile from Windows 8 on drive "D:\" ....

... **only to find that the old profile is nowhere to be found, AND that somehow the profile in "D:\Documents and Settings" directory seems to be an alias to "C:\Documents and Settings"** and not the original old profile.

Is this expected and due to the fact that my user ID is the same on both installs?

Is there a way to recover my old FireFox profile?

Comment: Hi - are you still able to boot the old Win8 installation..? If yes, then run "firefox -p" to find where the profile is located and you can the reference that location by running the same command under Win10. I suspect you may advertantly have copied the whole %userprofile% across rather than just the FF profile - which by default is created in the %userprofile%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Documents and Settings" hasn't been used since WinXP.

You'll find your original Firefox profile in

```
D:\Users\<user>\Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<randomchars>.default\
```

Note that to see the Appdata folder you'll need to enable "Show hidden files" in Explorer folder options.

Also, on your new computer/user, you'll notice the profile name (".default") will be different. Simply copy the **contents** of the old folder to the new one. Simply copying the whole folder won't work as FF isn't looking for that profile name.

So copy the **contents** of

```
D:\Users\<user>\Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<randomchars>.default\

to

C:\Users\<user>\Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<randomchars>.default\
```

Comment: the reason I spoke about Documents and Settings is because that's where I found FF profile directory. I suspect it was just symlinked from users\